# a js timer cannot run correctly

Tags: javascript

I put these code in the HEAD part of a html,but cannot run correctly,
is there any problem?

obviously it's a timer but it doesn't run even once.
I didnot forget to link the jquery.

thanks a lot.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    function something(){
        alert("something happened");
    }

    var timer=function(){
        something();
        setTimeout(timer,900);
    };

    timer;
}
);
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to call `something` every 900 milliseconds, you should use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout`: `setInterval(something, 900)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your outer anonymous function is run onready, but it just defines two function and then has a useless `timer` expression, you have to actually **call** the function: `timer()`.

If you want to do this properly, you should probably get rid of the `timer` function entirely, as you seem to be trying to simulate `setInterval`.

```
$(function(){
    function something(){
        alert("something happened");
    }

    setInterval(something, 900);
});
```

Comment: but why here "setInterval(something, 900);" can work,why not "setInterval("something()", 900);"?

Comment: maybe because you have to use 'timer()' instead of 'timer' to call your timer.

Comment: @namiheike — You can pass setInterval either a function or a string to be `eval`ed. The latter option breaks scope, is slow and is hard to debug. Passing a function is the better option.